# O Serial.read() do Arduino não funciona como esperado

Tags: c++, arduino, debug

No void loop, preciso que ele leia a dificuldade, em vez disso ele fica devolvendo a string no monitor.
Estou rodando 
 [nesse projeto tinkercad](https://www.tinkercad.com/things/7ALyi19QHeW-glorious-jarv-turing/editel?sharecode=TPuO7aC7o-dem38WW9THeGrWLau6J2beEOhqlAf1xxw=)

```
//Vamos começar definindo as notas para os sons

#define NOTE_D4  294

#define NOTE_G4  392

#define NOTE_A4  440

#define NOTE_A5  880


// criando o array para os 4 sons para sortear um som

int tons[4] = { NOTE_A5, NOTE_A4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_D4 };

// Nossa sequência de até 100 itens vai começar vazia.

int sequencia[100] = {};

// Indica a rodada atual que o jogo se encontra.

int rodada_atual = 0;

// Indica o passo atual dentro da sequência, é usado enquanto a sequência

// está sendo reproduzida.

int passo_atual_na_sequencia = 0;



/*

 * Indica o pino de áudio, leds e botões.

 * Os pinos de leds e botões estão em ordem, relacionados uns aos outros, ou

 * seja, o primeiro led está relacionado ao primeiro botão. A ordem destas

 * sequências também estão relacionadas a ordem dos tons.

 */

int pinoAudio = 7;

int pinosLeds[4] = { 8, 9, 10, 11 };

int pinosBotoes[4] = { 2, 3, 4, 5 };



// Indica se um botão foi pressionado durante o loop principal.

int botao_pressionado = 0;

// Flag indicando se o jogo acabou.

int perdeu_o_jogo = false;

int dificuldade = 999;

int nivel = 0;

bool comecoDoJogo = true;




void setup() {

    Serial.begin(9600);



  // Definindo o modo dos pinos dos Leds como saída.

  for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {

    pinMode(pinosLeds[i], OUTPUT);

  }


  // Definindo o modo dos pinos dos Botões como entrada.
  for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
    pinMode(pinosBotoes[i], INPUT);
  }


  // Definindo o modo do pino de Áudio como saída.

  pinMode(pinoAudio, OUTPUT);



  // Inicializando o random através de uma leitura da porta analógica.
  // Esta leitura gera um valor variável entre 0 e 1023.

  randomSeed(analogRead(0));

}

void loop() {

     Serial.println("Bem vindo ao jogo!");
    delay(500);
    Serial.println("Escolha uma dificuldade entre 1 e 3:");

    while (comecoDoJogo){

    while(dificuldade == 999){
         dificuldade = Serial.read();
    }

    delay(200);



        if(dificuldade >= 4 || dificuldade <= 0){

            Serial.println("Essa não é uma dificuldade válida. Por favor, escoha um número entre 1 e 3:");
            int a = dificuldade;
            while(a == dificuldade){
            dificuldade = Serial.read();
            }

        } else if(dificuldade <= 3 && dificuldade >= 1) {

            Serial.println("Oba, vamos jogar!");
            comecoDoJogo = false;
            delay(300);



        }






    nivel = dificuldade + 1;



}

  // Se perdeu o jogo reinicializamos todas as variáveis.

  if (perdeu_o_jogo) {

    int sequencia[100] = {};

    rodada_atual = 0;
    passo_atual_na_sequencia = 0;

    perdeu_o_jogo = false;

  }


  // Toca um som de início para anúnicar que o jogo está começando quando é a primeira rodada.
  if (rodada_atual == 0) {

    tocarSomDeInicio();

    delay(500);

  }


  // Chama a função que inicializa a próxima rodada.

  proximaRodada();

  // Reproduz a sequência atual.

  reproduzirSequencia();

  // Aguarda os botões serem pressionados pelo jogador.

  aguardarJogador();


  // Aguarda 1 segundo entre cada jogada.

  delay(1000);
}


// Sorteia um novo item e adiciona na sequência.

void proximaRodada() {

  int numero_sorteado = random(0, nivel);

  sequencia[rodada_atual++] = numero_sorteado;

}



// Reproduz a sequência para ser memorizada.

void reproduzirSequencia() {
  for (int i = 0; i < rodada_atual; i++) {

    tone(pinoAudio, tons[sequencia[i]]);

    digitalWrite(pinosLeds[sequencia[i]], HIGH);
    delay(500);

    noTone(pinoAudio);

    digitalWrite(pinosLeds[sequencia[i]], LOW);
    delay(100);

  }

  noTone(pinoAudio);

}



// Aguarda o jogador iniciar sua jogada.

void aguardarJogador() {

  for (int i = 0; i < rodada_atual; i++) {
    aguardarJogada();

    verificarJogada();


    if (perdeu_o_jogo) {

      break;
    }



    passo_atual_na_sequencia++;

  }



  // Redefine a variável para 0.

  passo_atual_na_sequencia = 0;
}


void aguardarJogada() {

  boolean jogada_efetuada = false;

  while (!jogada_efetuada) {

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {

      if (digitalRead(pinosBotoes[i]) == HIGH) {

        // Dizendo qual foi o botao pressionado.

        botao_pressionado = i;



        tone(pinoAudio, tons[i]);

        digitalWrite(pinosLeds[i], HIGH);

        delay(300);

        digitalWrite(pinosLeds[i], LOW);

        noTone(pinoAudio);



        jogada_efetuada = true;

      }

    }

    delay(10);
  }
}


void verificarJogada() {
  if (sequencia[passo_atual_na_sequencia] != botao_pressionado) {
    // GAME OVER.

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {
      tone(pinoAudio, tons[i]);
      digitalWrite(pinosLeds[i], HIGH);

      delay(200);

      digitalWrite(pinosLeds[i], LOW);
      noTone(pinoAudio);
    }



    tone(pinoAudio, tons[3]);

    for (int i = 0; i <= 3; i++) {

      digitalWrite(pinosLeds[0], HIGH);

      digitalWrite(pinosLeds[1], HIGH);

      digitalWrite(pinosLeds[2], HIGH);

      digitalWrite(pinosLeds[3], HIGH);

      delay(100);

      digitalWrite(pinosLeds[0], LOW);

      digitalWrite(pinosLeds[1], LOW);

      digitalWrite(pinosLeds[2], LOW);

      digitalWrite(pinosLeds[3], LOW);

      delay(100);

    }

    noTone(pinoAudio);



    perdeu_o_jogo = true;

  }

}

void tocarSomDeInicio() {

  tone(pinoAudio, tons[0]);

  digitalWrite(pinosLeds[0], HIGH);

  digitalWrite(pinosLeds[1], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinosLeds[2], HIGH);
  digitalWrite(pinosLeds[3], HIGH);

  delay(500);

  digitalWrite(pinosLeds[0], LOW);
  digitalWrite(pinosLeds[1], LOW);
  digitalWrite(pinosLeds[2], LOW);

  digitalWrite(pinosLeds[3], LOW);
  delay(500);
  noTone(pinoAudio);
}
```

Comment: Link do projeto no tinkercad está fora

Comment: Perdão pelo link falho. Agora ele deve funcionar :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quando você envia um 1 do serial você está enviando um ASCII 1.
Como você está lendo isso em uma variável do timpo int o arduino entende isso com o seu valor hexadecimal. Se der um print ai ele vai estar lendo 49. Você pode pesquisar no Google pela tabela ascii para ver o valor hexa de cada caracter.

Você precisa pegar o valor que está vindo da serial para uma variável char e aí converter para int usando a função atoi() ou alguma outra forma de conversão.

Seria algo do tipo usando o atoi:

```
char recebido[0];
int dificuldade;

recebido = Serial.read();
dificuldade = atoi(recebido);
```

Comment: A execução foi melhor usando int() para converter. Obrigado pela resposta, me ajudou! :)